# Strange query grouping in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE prices2
(  
   id_price     integer primary key,
   date        text, 
   value       real
);
```

And let's say I have this values:

```
insert into prices2( '01/01/2017', 1 ); 
insert into prices2( '02/01/2017', 2 ); 
insert into prices2( '02/01/2017', 3 ); 
insert into prices2( '04/01/2017', 7 ); 
insert into prices2( '04/01/2017', 6 );
```

I wonder why this select is correct and returns some results, and what is returning:

```
select date, 
       count(*)  
  from prices2
 where date 
 group by date like '%/01/2017';
```

Maybe "date like "%/01/2017" is a boolean expression that returns some kind of value???

Comment: What results is it returning, and why does that surprise you?

Comment: the surprise is that works. It's a mistake I made, my real question was select date, 
       count(*)  
  from prices2
 where date  like '%/01/2017'
 group by date; which is a more correct question

Answer (score 1):

`date like '%/01/2017'` indeed is a boolean expression; in SQLite, it returns either `0` or `1`:

```
> select date, date like '%/01/2017' from prices2;
01/01/2017|1
02/01/2017|1
02/01/2017|1
04/01/2017|1
04/01/2017|1
```

So when you use this expression in the GROUP BY clause, you get one group for `1` values, and one group each for `0` and `NULL` values (but there are none in this example).

As for `where date`, the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#booleanexpr) says:

> The SQL language features several contexts where an expression is evaluated and the result converted to a boolean (true or false) value. These contexts are:
>
> - the WHERE clause of a SELECT, UPDATE or DELETE statement,
> - [...]
>
> To convert the results of an SQL expression to a boolean value, SQLite first casts the result to a NUMERIC value in the same way as a CAST expression. A numeric zero value (integer value 0 or real value 0.0) is considered to be false. A NULL value is still NULL. All other values are considered true.

The `date` values begin with a number that is not zero, so they are interpreted as true.